# How to deal with hidden file extensions

Tags: c#, file-extension

Here's a piece of code:

```
if (fbFolderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   originalFiles = Directory.GetFiles(fbFolderBrowser.SelectedPath);
   supportedFiles = originalFiles.Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".bmp") || s.EndsWith(".tiff") || s.EndsWith(".jpeg") || s.EndsWith(".gif")).ToArray();
}
```

What if in the directory selected, the files' extensions are hidden? Does it mean I won't be able to use "EndsWith?"

What would be the correct way to KNOW the file extensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hiding file extensions is a behavior of the UI run by the Windows shell.

It has no effect on your code;  all actual filepaths will still have extensions.

Bonus: Look at the `Path.GetExtension()` method.

Comment: okay so you're saying that if I run the command "EndsWith" on a file that has hidden extension, it'll still be able to read ".jpg" for example?

Comment: @Testifier: There is no such as a "file that has hidden extension".  Windows Explorer (and other shell dialogs) will not display extensions by default, but that has no effect whatsoever on the filesystem.  Any string that you get from the filesystem will always have an extension.  (except for files taht actually don't have any extension, of course)

Comment: Thanks Slaks & Abe. I'll accept your answer. Still need 2 mins tho :(

Answer (score 1):

You will still see the extension if you access the directory from code.  The "hidden" extension only hides it when browsing to files through the UI.